# Parse XML with Simple XML [Java Android]

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

How to parse this XML:

```
<resources> 
    <string name="name1">content1</string> 
    <string name="name2">content2</string> 
    <string name="name3">content3</string> 
    ...
</resources>
```

**I can't create objects with the correct annotations to retrieve both the name and content.**

My current work:

```
@Root(name = "resources")
public class Translation {

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private List<TranslationName> translationNames;

    public List<TranslationName> getTranslationNames() {
        return translationNames;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Root(name = "string")
public class TranslationName {

    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Element(name = "string")
    private String content;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

But I have:

> Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false,
>   name=string, required=true, type=void) on field 'content'

**EDIT:**

With this I successfully recovered the content:

```
@Root(name = "resources")
public class Translation {

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private List<String> contentNames;

    public List<String> getContentNames() {
        return contentNames;
    }
}
```

But with the combination of the two it does not work:

```
@Root(name = "resources")
public class Translation {

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private List<TranslationName> translationNames;
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private List<String> contentNames;

    public List<TranslationName> getTranslationNames() {
        return translationNames;
    }

    public List<String> getContentNames() {
        return contentNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure can u try this put (required=false) for "content" and try?

Comment: If I do that it won't recover the "content"

Comment: Does this also appear when testing with a minimal version (1 string)? So maybe there is a corrupted one? The code itself seems pretty ok to me.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael can u check your xml data. i.e "content" field is not empty?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825380/very-easy-to-solve-issue-with-simplexml-what-im-doing-wrong). I hope it might help you

Comment: @Raghavendra Yes all work well without Content. But I need to recover this also. I tryied to remove '@Element(name = "string")' with your link but it's the same result, the content is also null

Comment: @Raghavendra If I set (required=false) it works but my "content" is always null. Please check my question, I edited.

Answer (score 1):

You classes gives xml like

```
 <resources>
   <string name="name1"> <string>content1</string>   </string>
   <string name="name2"> <string>content2</string>   </string>
   <string name="name3"><string>content3</string>   </string>
 </resources>
```

for content attribute replace by:

```
@Text
    private String content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying out magic combinations of annotations to make something happen, you can simply code the XML parser yourself. Don't use Stax/pull - that's too low-level and hard and error-prone to use directly. Try [Konsume-XML](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/konsume-xml):

```
data class Resource(val name: String, val content: String)

val konsumer = """
<resources>
    <string name="name1">content1</string>
    <string name="name2">content2</string>
    <string name="name3">content3</string>
</resources>
""".trimIndent().konsumeXml()
val resources: List<Resource> = konsumer.child("resources") {
    children("string") {
        Resource(attributes["name"], text())
    }
}
println(resources)
```

will print

```
[Resource(name=name1, content=content1), Resource(name=name2, content=content2), Resource(name=name3, content=content3)]
```